# Rendering objects with multiple VAOs and VBOs

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, vbo, vao

I'm learning OpenGL. My task is to develop a program for rendering lots of different objects downloaded as .obj files. My idea is to create a class for storing 3 VBOs (vertex, texture, normals), a VAO and the type of object together in one class object. So, similar objects (for rendering) will use just one class object with the right VAO and VBOs. I coded it, but it does not work: The object gets download from file, all class objects are create, but nothing is drawn on screen.

Class for storing VAOs and VBOs, constructor for this class:

```
modelMemory(char* typeT)
{
    this->modelType = typeT;

    if (this->modelType == "Suzanne")   loadOBJ("suzanne.obj", this->vertices, this->uvs, this->normals);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO_id);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO_id);

    glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO_vertex);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO_vertex);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &this->vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
/**/glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO_uv);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO_uv);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->uvs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &this->uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
/**/glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO_normal);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO_normal);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &this->normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
/**/glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
/*DESTRUCTOR*/
~modelMemory()
{
/**/if (toDel)
    {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO_vertex);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO_uv);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO_normal);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO_id);
    }
}
```

Class for storing models, constructor:

```
Model2 (char* Type, float x, float y, float z, std::vector<modelMemory>* M, GLuint programID)
{
    this->type = Type;
    this->programID = programID;

    unsigned int k = 0;

    if ((*M).size() > 0){
        while(this->type != (*M)[k].modelType && k < (*M).size()) k++;
        if (k < (*M).size()) this->mem = &((*M)[k]);
    }
    if ((*M).size() == 0 || k == (*M).size()){
        //modelMemory newModel(this->type);
        //(*M).push_back(newModel);
        /**/(*M).emplace_back(this->type);  
        this->mem = &((*M)[(*M).size()-1]);
    }

    ModelPosition[0] += x;
    ModelPosition[1] += y;
    ModelPosition[2] += z;

    MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
    ViewMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "V");
    ModelMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "M");

    TextureID  = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "myTextureSampler");
    Texture = loadDDS("uvmap.DDS");
}
```

And function for drawing:

```
void Draw()
{
    glUseProgram(programID);
    computeMatricesFromInputs();
    glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
    glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = getViewMatrix();
    glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), ModelPosition);

    glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix; 

    glUniformMatrix4fv(this->MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(this->ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(this->ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->Texture);
    glUniform1i(this->TextureID, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(this->mem->VAO_id);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, this->mem->vertices.size());

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I create a vector in main.cpp:

```
std::vector<modelMemory> Memory;
std::vector<Model2> ModelList;
```

And calls for creating and drawing in main.cpp:

```
ModelList.emplace_back((char*)"Field", 0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f, &Memory, programID);
ModelList.emplace_back((char*)"Suzanne", 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, &Memory, programID);
ModelList.emplace_back((char*)"Suzanne", 4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, &Memory, programID);

for (int i = 0; i < ModelList.size(); i++)
        ModelList[i].Draw();
```

Shaders (actually, I am not as good as it possible in shaders, they depends on OpenGL lessons). 
Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexNormal_modelspace;

out vec2 UV;
out vec3 Position_worldspace;
out vec3 Normal_cameraspace;
out vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace;
out vec3 LightDirection_cameraspace;

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;
uniform vec3 LightPosition_worldspace;

void main(){

    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);

    Position_worldspace = (M * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1)).xyz;

    vec3 vertexPosition_cameraspace = ( V * M * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1)).xyz;
    EyeDirection_cameraspace = vec3(0,0,0) - vertexPosition_cameraspace;

    vec3 LightPosition_cameraspace = ( V * vec4(LightPosition_worldspace,1)).xyz;
    LightDirection_cameraspace = LightPosition_cameraspace + EyeDirection_cameraspace;

    Normal_cameraspace = ( V * M * vec4(vertexNormal_modelspace,0)).xyz; 

    UV = vertexUV;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

vec2 UV;
in vec3 Position_worldspace;
in vec3 Normal_cameraspace;
in vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace;
in vec3 LightDirection_cameraspace;

out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler;
uniform mat4 MV;
uniform vec3 LightPosition_worldspace;

void main(){

    vec3 LightColor = vec3(1,1,1);
    float LightPower = 10.0f;

    vec3 MaterialDiffuseColor = texture( myTextureSampler, UV ).rgb;
    vec3 MaterialAmbientColor = vec3(0.1,0.1,0.1) * MaterialDiffuseColor;
    vec3 MaterialSpecularColor = vec3(0.3,0.3,0.3);

    float distance = length( LightPosition_worldspace - Position_worldspace );

    vec3 n = normalize( Normal_cameraspace );
    vec3 l = normalize( LightDirection_cameraspace );
    float cosTheta = clamp( dot( n,l ), 0.1,1 );

    vec3 E = normalize(EyeDirection_cameraspace);
    vec3 R = reflect(-l,n);
    float cosAlpha = clamp( dot( E,R ), 0.4,1 );

    color = 
        MaterialAmbientColor +
        MaterialDiffuseColor * LightColor * LightPower * cosTheta / (distance*distance) +
        MaterialSpecularColor * LightColor * LightPower * pow(cosAlpha,6) / (distance*distance);
}
```

Comment: `glEnableVertexAttribArray` should go to the VAO initialization code. No need to enable and disable it every frame. Could you please add your shaders? Without them it is hard to judge if the attribute setup is fine.

Comment: This part could also be problematic depending on what your destructor does: `modelMemory newModel(this->type);         (*M).push_back(newModel);`. It would be good if you add a more complete example.

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes, perspective projection. But Im absolute sure, that there is not any objects. Could you, please, explain, why glBindBuffer is superfluous in Draw()? (I tried without glBindBuffer in Void(), but it also does not work)

Comment: @Rabbid76 you could see, that ModelMatrix is changing all the time: `ModelMatrix = glm::translate(ModelMatrix, glm::vec3(float(cos(glfwGetTime())), float(sin(glfwGetTime())), 0.3* float(sin(glfwGetTime()*4))));`. I have tried your variant, but it also does not work.  @BDL Shaders were added. So, I should enable Vertex attributes just one time when initialize VAO (after binding VAO)? Even I have more than one VAO? Hm, I have not code destructors yet, what should they contain for properly work?

Comment: @Rabbid76 they returns Projection and View matrix, which changing when you move mouse. I just turned it off and write simple projection and view matrix without mouse moving, and it also does not work)

Comment: Are you deleting Opengl objects (vbo/VAO/...) in the destructor of the modelmemory class?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Hi! I have updated my code (/**/ before code means new code, commented code means deleted code): i have changed creating vao and vbos, drawing, and write destructor for vbos and vaos, and realized, that destructor calls 2 times, 1st - in Model2 constructor (marked with /*destructor worked*/), 2-nd - at the end of the program. Could it be the problem? It still not working.

Comment: @BDL Hi! I have updated my code (/**/ before code means new code, commented code means deleted code): i have changed creating vao and vbos, drawing, and write destructor for vbos and vaos, and realized, that destructor calls 2 times, 1st - in Model2 constructor (marked with /*destructor worked*/), 2-nd - at the end of the program. Could it be the problem? It still not working.

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes, I use .push_back, next after `modelMemory newModel(this->type);`, I put breakpoint in destructor, but how it should help me? I checked VAO and VBOs in Draw(), value the same, but i dont know, how to check memory, is it still exist or not.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have problem with understanding logic of program: 1) we create modelMemory object #1 -> generate VAO and VBOs (start using gpu memory), 2) .push_back() modelMemory object #1 to vector<modelMemory>, so, creates modelMemory object #2 in vector 3) temporary modelMemory object #1 destroys (so, VAO and VBOs delete, and, how I can understand, gpu memory, using for both #1 and #2 modelMemory objects, also destroys - that's why nothing is drawn) 4) at the end of program all objects from vector are destroyed. Am I right with logic and memory?

Comment: @Rabbid76 nice, so, could you help me with fixing it?))

Comment: @Rabbid76 Hi, again :) So, it works, little. Now it draws some objects only one type, using similar modelMemory object. BUT, if I have some objects different types (using different modelMemory objects: like in main(): one of objects - field, and two others - Suzanne), only last two Suzanne objects will be drawn. I checked - now GL memory exists all time for all objects. What could be a problem? Sorry for my questions, but I still can`t understand how some OpenGL stuff works.